# back to original after word-tokenize

Tags: python-3.x, list, tokenize

I have 10,563 reviews and I applied pre-processing steps like tokenizing, normalization, stop word removal and etc. my problem is how to save the results into excel file back as reviews.

```
cl_data = []
x = ''.join(str(v) for v in reviews)
norm = normalize(x)
sw = stopwords.words('english')
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(x)
stopped_tokens = [i for i in tokens if not i in sw]
exclude = set(string.punctuation)
punc_free = [ch for ch in stopped_tokens if ch not in exclude]
norm_ar =  [no for no in punc_free if no  in norm]
```

the result is a list of words for each review like this:

```
[ 'great','place'......]
```

any help? thanks in advance

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I want to save the results as sentences(full clean review) not words

Comment: `' '.join()` them?